# How to browse to a folder with plotly dash?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am learning Python Dashboard. I know that there is a Dash core components upload allow to upload a file. What I need is load all of files in a folder. I would like to know how to use a core component to browse to a select folder then read all files in that folder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [tag:dash] is probably not the Dash you're talking about. What exactly *are* you talking about?

Comment: I am talking about Dash from Plotly. https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components

Comment: Have you managed to figure this out? I'm looking for the same thing, though for me it would be enough to just get the path.

Comment: I don't think we can do that because of the security thing. I can only find the upload tool of dash allow to upload single or multiple files. Please update me if you can find any tool.

Comment: Is this question about uploading all files in a folder to server? Or just opening folder and reading the filenames?

Comment: @NikoPasanen In my case it'd be the latter. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `dash_core_components.Upload` component and set `multiple=True` to upload multiple files. Here is an example: https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/upload.

This, however, uploads all the contents of all the files at once. What you cannot do with it is just get the contents of a folder, so that you can upload the files one by one.

However, since your question *is* about uploading all files in a folder, this should do it.

Comment: In Windows, you can use "Ctrl+A" to select everything in a folder (I believe you can use "Cmd+A" on Mac instead)

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to use the `os` built-in library to navigate the files inside the server hosting the Dash app - this means your computer if you are running locally, or on the VM if you are hosting on the cloud.

As mentioned by ThangNguyen, it's not possible to browse the files on the client side. So if your app is hosted on a cloud instance, it won't be able to read the files the computer you are using to visit the app.

If your goal is to indeed navigate the files on the server, then you can use the following code:

```py
import os

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
server = app.server

folders = ["images", "spreadsheets"]

controls = [
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id="dropdown",
        options=[{"label": x, "value": x} for x in folders],
        value=folders[0],
    )
]

app.layout = html.Div(
    [html.H1("File Browser"), html.Div(controls), html.Div(id="folder-files")]
)


@app.callback(Output("folder-files", "children"), Input("dropdown", "value"))
def list_all_files(folder_name):
    # This is relative, but you should be able
    # able to provide the absolute path too
    file_names = os.listdir(folder_name)

    file_list = html.Ul([html.Li(file) for file in file_names])

    return file_list


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Given a folder structure like this one:

[image: folder structure]

You should get the following app:

[image: demo of the app in action]