# Python Dash plotly : Select a File in a URL (Browse Functionality)

Tags: python, plotly-python

I am using dash in Python for the first time .

Is there any method / module i can use with Python dash that i can use to achieve the browse functionality i.e on a click of button an url should open and should be able to navigate through website in a different window and select a file of my choice . The selected file's URL should be captured in to a text box .

I find examples to upload files , But haven't found a example to select a file from URL . Any suggestions please ?
[How to browse to a folder with plotly dash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52980495/how-to-browse-to-a-folder-with-plotly-dash)

Comment: Any help please ?

Comment: Could you simply let the user copy a value into a text input? The UX you're describing sounds like it would be a lot of work to set up.

Comment: I already have a api to fetch this URL , Incase the URL needs to be changed by the USER , I just want to redirect him to a web site and allow him to select a file

Comment: I see. I'm not aware of any existing Dash component that handles all of that functionality, so you may need to create a new custom component.